# Should I use // or /// to comment in Dart? Does it make the app slower?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I check the code from packages I see they use both **//** and **///** to comment.

> // is a normal comment.
>
> /// *is a highlighted comment*.

It seems like using /// is better, so why do they using both of them? And does it make the app slower when using comments in Dart?

Answer (score 1):

DO use /// doc comments to document members and types.

Using a doc comment instead of a regular comment enables [dartdoc](https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc) to find it and generate documentation for it.

Example:

```
    /// The number of characters in this chunk when unsplit.
int get length => ...
```

See the official guide [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation#do-use--doc-comments-to-document-members-and-types).

---

For historical reasons, dartdoc supports two syntaxes of doc comments: `///` (“C# style”) and `/** ... */` (“JavaDoc style”). We prefer `///` because it’s more compact. `/** and */` add two content-free lines to a multiline doc comment. The `///` syntax is also easier to read in some situations, such as when a doc comment contains a bulleted list that uses * to mark list items.

If you stumble onto code that still uses the JavaDoc style, consider cleaning it up.

---

### do it make the app slow when using comment in Dart?

No, dart compiler will remove them from the release build.

Answer (score 1):

First it's not affect on speed of your codes, the complier just igonre it, it's for you and for other developers.

Second, `//` it's just a normal comment for normal text or code you don't use for now. But `///` it's used for document your code and explain what your function or code is supposed to do.

You can read full DartDoc from http://dartdoc.takyam.com/articles/doc-comment-guidelines/